# Saving custom class to Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a class called "Date" that I create in my app. I want to save newly created Date objects to Core Data, but I am getting

> Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be
>   represented in Objective-C

Here is my model code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(MyModel)
class MyModel: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dateObject: Date
}
```

I don't know enough about Core Data yet to understand how to do this without using NSManaged (if that's indeed the solution.) Can someone help, at least by pointing me in the right direction for where to read more about this- a solution would of course be better :).

Thanks.

Comment: What did you do in your Core Data Model Editor? Did you set your MyModel Entity? How do you call your class? Are you creating a pure Swift project?

Comment: Yes, pure swift. I have one attribute in my entity. That is dateObject of type Date

Comment: No need for `@objc(MyModel)` if you have a pure Swift project. But in order to use your class MyModel with Core Data, you will have to prefix the class name in the Class field of the Core Data model entity inspector with the name of your module. For example: "theNameofMyApp.MyModel" (see the picture at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html)).

Comment: Did you mark your `Date` class with `@objc` attribute?

Comment: I followed the directive on the Apple page. Still getting the error about the @NSManaged

Comment: make it optional. i.e. `Date!` or `Date?`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@NSManaged var dateObject: NSDate?
```